# How do I prevent pictures stacking when I insert them into word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, picture-import-wizard

I regularly have to insert pictures into word.  I used to be able to use the 'insert pictures' option and word would position the pictures one after the other expanding the document the required number of pages.  For some unknown reason this has changed.  Now when I go to insert > pictures it stacks them all on a single page.  I've tried adjusting all sorts of settings but without joy.  The only way I've found around this is to copy and paste the pictures one at a time, inserting a page break each time.

Does anyone know what setting I've inadvertently changed and how I can change it back?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File > Options > Advanced

Scroll down to the "Cut, copy, and paste" section. Fine the "Insert/paste pictures as:" drop-down box. It's probably set as "In front of text" but it could be something else. It sounds you like you want to use "In line with text".

[image: Screenshot]

Also, as was pointed out in the comments, you can change any image's text wrapping after it's been inserted. When the image is selected, a button will appear near the top right corner that you can click on to change the wrapping for that image.

[image: ChangeTheImageAfterTheFact_HiFutureEditors]

Comment: In addition to this answer, once you paste the image, a small icon appears in the top right corner of the image where you can change this behavior for that image too.

Comment: Thank's very much that worked 1st time